# Tensorflow bug? Can't restore single saved variable to a architecture saved with all the variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can load an architecture("A") and restore a single specific Tensorflow variable with a different architecture("B") only if when I save architecture "A" I only save the single variable that I saved for "B".

This works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

####################################################
# Architecture "A"
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(0.0, 0.5, 6), name="w1")
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(1.0, 5.0, 6), name="w2")

saver = tf.train.Saver({'w1':w1})  #<---------- Save only w1

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver.save(sess, './my_architecture')

tf.reset_default_graph()
####################################################
# Architecture "B"
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(10.0, 50.0, 6), name="w1")
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(100.0, 500.0, 6), name="w2")

saver = tf.train.Saver({'w1':w1})
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver.save(sess, './my_variable')  

tf.reset_default_graph()
######################################################
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Loading the model structure from 'my_test_model.meta'
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_architecture.meta')

  # Loading the saved "w1" Variable
  new_saver.restore(sess,'./my_variable')
```

This doesn't work only; I only changed `saver = tf.train.Saver({'w1':w1})` to `saver = tf.train.Saver()` 8 lines down:

```
import tensorflow as tf

####################################################
# Architecture "A"
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(0.0, 0.5, 6), name="w1")
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(1.0, 5.0, 6), name="w2")

saver = tf.train.Saver()  #<---------- Save everything

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver.save(sess, './my_architecture')

tf.reset_default_graph()
####################################################
# Architecture "B"
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(10.0, 50.0, 6), name="w1")
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(100.0, 500.0, 6), name="w2")

saver = tf.train.Saver({'w1':w1})
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

saver.save(sess, './my_variable')  

tf.reset_default_graph()
######################################################
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Loading the model structure from 'my_test_model.meta'
  new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_architecture.meta')

  # Loading the saved "w1" Variable
  new_saver.restore(sess,'./my_variable')
```

In other words, if when saving the architecture for "A" I save all the variables or any combination that is not solely the variable I saved for architecture "B"

I get this error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./my_variable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1038     try:
-> 1039       return fn(*args)
   1040     except errors.OpError as e:

/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1020                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1021                                  status, run_metadata)
   1022 

/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

NotFoundError: Key w2 not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_3 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_11_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bc6592a722bf> in <module>()
     42 
     43   # Loading the saved "w1" Variable
---> 44   new_saver.restore(sess,'./my_variable')
     45 
     46 #   initialize_uninitialized_vars(sess)

/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in restore(self, sess, save_path)
   1455     logging.info("Restoring parameters from %s", save_path)
   1456     sess.run(self.saver_def.restore_op_name,
-> 1457              {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
   1458 
   1459   @staticmethod

/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

NotFoundError: Key w2 not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_3 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_11_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2_1', defined at:
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/home/paul/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-bc6592a722bf>", line 41, in <module>
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./my_architecture.meta')
  File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1595, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 499, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 308, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key w2 not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_3 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_11_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `Saver` created by importing a metagraph will attempt to restore all of the variables in that metagraph (and will complain about variables that are missing from the checkpoint). However, it is possible to filter those variables based on another checkpoint:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  ####################################################
  # Architecture "A"
  w1 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(0.0, 0.5, 6), name="w1")
  w2 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(1.0, 5.0, 6), name="w2")

  saver = tf.train.Saver()  #<---------- Save everything

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    saver.save(sess, '/tmp/my_architecture')

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  ####################################################
  # Architecture "B"
  w1 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(10.0, 50.0, 6), name="w1")
  w2 = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(100.0, 500.0, 6), name="w2")

  saver = tf.train.Saver({'w1':w1})
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.save(sess, '/tmp/my_variable')

restored_graph = tf.Graph()
with restored_graph.as_default():
  tf.train.import_meta_graph('/tmp/my_architecture.meta')
  vars_to_restore = [
      restored_graph.get_tensor_by_name(var_name + ':0') for var_name, _ 
      in tf.contrib.framework.list_variables('/tmp/my_variable')]
  filtered_saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=vars_to_restore)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore w1 from Architecture "B" into the metagraph from Architecture "A"
    filtered_saver.restore(sess,'/tmp/my_variable')
    print(restored_graph.get_tensor_by_name('w1:0').eval())
```

Prints:

> [ 10.  18.  26.  34.  42.  50.]